# how to add a "space" in certain location in string when scraping the data from web by using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I was scraping a web for practicing and I encountered a problem.

I'd like to print data like:

> Level :2
>
> DC Fast :12
>
> Level :2

I used `browser[0].find("div",{"class":"pin_info"}).text[1:]` However, what I got is`Level :2DC Fast :12Level :2`, there is no space between each part.

Below is the html I scraped:

```
<div class="pin_info"> 
  <span class="pinID">A</span> 
  <i style="background-image:url('/UI/images/icons/new_icons/cg_un.png?1000017283')"></I>
  <span class="dark">Level 2</span>
  : 2
  <br>
  <span class="dark">DC Fast</span>
  : 12
  <br>
  <span class="dark">Level 2</span>
  : 2
</div>
```

I have no clue how to separate each part right now. Does anybody have any ideas? 
  Any response will be appreciated!

Comment: which library are you using ? can you please provide more code you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getText method instead of the .text attribute, since it has an optional separator argument which allows you to replace separations with whatever you want ("\n" here) like this:

`browser[0].find("div",{"class":"pin_info"}).getText(separator="\n")`

Result:

```
A


Level 2
: 2

DC Fast
: 12

Level 2
: 2
```

Then you can do string manipulation with that until you get to your desired result, something like this:

```
info = browser[0].find("div",{"class":"pin_info"}).getText(separator="\n")[5:].split("\n\n")
'\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", " "), info))
```

Output:

```
Level 2 : 2
DC Fast : 12
Level 2 : 2
```